# SwiftUI - share dictionary among views, unclear what arguments to use at @Main / WindowGroup

Tags: dictionary, swiftui, initializer, observedobject, swiftui-windowgroup

I'm trying to build an app (macOS, but would be the same for iOS) that creates a number of grids, the outcome of which is to be shown in a second screen. For this, I'm sharing data across these screens, and I'm running into an issue here, I hope someone can help or point me in the right direction. I'll share a simplified version of the code below (working in Xcode 14.0.1)

The code creates a dictionary that can be shown in a grid, on which calculations can be done. The idea is then to add this grid, with some descriptive variables, into another dictionary

The building blocks of the grid are cells

```
Import Foundation
struct Cell: Comparable, Equatable, Identifiable, Hashable {
    static func == (lhs: Cell, rhs: Cell) -> Bool {
        lhs.randomVarOne == rhs.randomVarOne
    }
    var randomVarOne: Double
    var randomVarTwo: Bool
    // other vars omitted here
    var id: Int { randomVarOne } 
    static func < (lhs: Cell, rhs: Cell) -> Bool {
            return lhs.randomVarOne < rhs.randomVarOne
    }
}
```

this is also where there are a bunch of funcs to calculate next neighbor cells in the grid etc

then the grid is defined in a class:

```
class Info: ObservableObject, Hashable {
    static func == (lhs: Info, rhs: Info) -> Bool {
        lhs.grid == rhs.grid
    }
    func hash(into hasher: inout Hasher) {
            hasher.combine(grid)
        }
    @Published var grid = [Cell]()

    var arrayTotal = 900
    @Published var toBeUsedForTheGridCalculations: Double = 0.0
    var toBeUsedToSetTheVarAbove: Double = 0.0
    var rowTotalDouble: Double {sqrt(Double(arrayTotal)) }
    var rowTotal: Int {
        Int(rowTotalDouble) != 0 ? Int(rowTotalDouble) : 10 }
```

The class includes a func to create and populate the grid with Cells and add these Cells to the grid var. It also includes the formulas to do the calculations on the grid using a user input. The class did not seem to need an initializer.

This is the Scenario struct:

```
struct Scenario: Comparable, Equatable, Identifiable, Hashable {
    static func == (lhs: Scenario, rhs: Scenario) -> Bool {
        lhs.scenarioNumber == rhs.scenarioNumber
    }
    func hash(into hasher: inout Hasher) {
            hasher.combine(scenarioNumber)
        }
    var scenarioNumber: Int
    var date: Date
    var thisIsOneSnapshot = [Info]()
    var id: Int { scenarioNumber }
    static func < (lhs: Scenario, rhs: Scenario) -> Bool {
        return lhs.scenarioNumber < rhs.scenarioNumber
    }
}
```

added hashable since it uses the Info class as an input.

Then there is the class showing the output overview

```
class OutputOverview: ObservableObject {
    @Published var snapshot = [Scenario]()
```

// the class includes a formula of how to add the collection of cells (grid) and the additional variables to the snapshot dictionary. Again no initializer was necessary.

Now to go to the ContentView.

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @Environment(\.openURL) var openURL
    var scenarioNumberInput: Int = 0
    var timeStampAssigned: Date = Date.now

    @ObservedObject private var currentGrid: Info = Info()
    @ObservedObject private var scenarios: Combinations = Combinations()

    var usedForTheCalculations: Double = 0.0

    var rows =
    [
        GridItem(.flexible()),
     // whole list of GridItems, I do not know how to calculate these: 
     // var rows = Array(repeating: GridItem(.flexible()), count: currentGrid.rowTotal) 
     //gives error "Cannot use instance member 'currentGrid' within property initializer;
     // property iunitializers run before 'self' is available
    ]
    var body: some View {
        
        GeometryReader { geometry in
            VStack {
                ScrollView {
                    LazyHGrid(rows: rows, spacing: 0) {
                        ForEach(0..<currentGrid.grid.count, id :\.self) { w in
                            let temp = currentGrid.grid[w].varThatAffectsFontColor
                            let temp2 = currentGrid.grid[w].varThatAffectsBackground
                            Text("\(currentGrid.grid[w].randomVarOne, specifier: "%.2f")")
                                .frame(width: 25, height: 25)
                                .border(.black)
                                .font(.system(size: 7))
                                .foregroundColor(Color(wordName: temp))
                                .background(Color(wordName: temp2))
                        }
                    }
                    .padding(.top)
                }
                VStack{
                    HStack {
                        Button("Start") {
                   
                        }
                // then some buttons to do the calculations
                        Button("Add to collection"){
                            scenarios.addScenario(numbering: scenarioNumberInput, timeStamp:
                         Date.now, collection: currentGrid.grid)
                        } // this should add the newly recalculated grid to the dictionary
                        Button("Go to Results") {
                           guard let url = URL(string: "myapp://scenario") else { return }
                           openURL(url)         
                        } // to go to the screen showing the scenarios
```

Then the second View, the ScenarioView:

```
struct ScenarioView: View {
    @State var selectedScenario = 1
    @ObservedObject private var scenarios: OutputOverview
    
    var pickerNumbers = [ 1, 2, 3, 4 , 5] 
    // this is to be linked to the number of scenarios completed,this code is not done yet.
    var rows =
    [
        GridItem(.flexible()),
        GridItem(.flexible()),
     // similar list of GridItems here....

    var body: some View {
        Form {
            Section {
                Picker("Select a scenario", selection: $selectedScenario) { 
                  ForEach(pickerNumbers, id: \.self) {
                    Text("\($0)")
                    
                }
                }
            }
            Section {
                ScrollView {
                    if let idx = scenarios.snapshot.firstIndex(where: 
                      {$0.scenarioNumber == selectedScenario}) {
                        LazyHGrid(rows: rows, spacing: 0) {
                            
                            ForEach(0..<scenarios.snapshot[idx].thisIsOneSnapshot.count, 
                                id :\.self) { w in
                                let temp =
                         scenarios.snapshot[idx].thisIsOneSnapshot[w].varThatAffectsFontColor
                                let temp2 = 
                         scenarios.snapshot[idx].thisIsOneSnapshot[w].varThatAffectsBackground
                                Text("\(scenarios.snapshot[idx].thisIsOneSnapshot[w].randomVarOne, specifier: "%.2f")")
                                    .frame(width: 25, height: 25)
                                    .border(.black)
                                    .font(.system(size: 7))
                                    .foregroundColor(Color(wordName: temp))
                                    .background(Color(wordName: temp2))
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Now while the above does not (for the moment..) give me error messages, I am not able to run the PreviewProvider in the second View. The main problem is in @main:

```
import SwiftUI

@main
struct ThisIsTheNameOfMyApp: App {
 
    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            ContentView()
        }
        .handlesExternalEvents(matching: ["main"])
        
        WindowGroup("Scenarios") {
            ScenarioView()

       // error messages here: 'ScenarioView' initializer is inaccessible due to "private"
       // protection level - I don't know what is set to private in ScenarioView that could
       // cause this
       // second error message: missing argument for parameter 'scenarios' in call
        }
        .handlesExternalEvents(matching: ["scenario"])
    }
}
```

I am at a loss on how to solve these 2 error messages and would be very grateful for any tips or guidance. Apologies if this question is very long, I scanned many other forum questions and could not find any good answers.

I have tried adding pro forma data in @main as follows

```
@main
struct FloodModelScenarioViewerApp: App {
    @State var scenarios = Scenario(scenarioNumber: 1, date: Date.now)
    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            ContentView()
        }
        .handlesExternalEvents(matching: ["main"])
        
        WindowGroup("Scenarios") {
            ScenarioView(scenarios: scenarios)

        }
        .handlesExternalEvents(matching: ["scenario"])
    }
}
```

This still gives 2 error messages:

- same issue with regards to ScenarioView initialiser being inaccessible due to being 'private'
- Cannot convert value of type 'Scenario' to expected argument type 'OutputOverview'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just remove the `private` from

```
@ObservedObject private var scenarios: OutputOverview
```

The value is coming from he parent so the parent needs access. So put

```
@StateObject private var scenarios: OutputOverview = .init()
```

in `FloodModelScenarioViewerApp`

`@StateObject` is for initializing `ObservableObject`s and `@ObservedObject` is for passing them around.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if your code will work after you read this question, and that's because there are many things to correct, but you can start with these:

1. In `Cell`, you shouldn't use an `id` that is a variable, this may cause inconsistent behavior. Use something like:

```
let id = UUID()
```

2. When you initialize `ContentView`, you can't use `currentGrid` inside a variable because `currentGrid` will not be available before all variables are initialized. Meaning, you are trying to initialize `rows` before `currentGrid` actually exists. You can try using the `.onAppear` modifier:

```
    var rows = [GridItem]()

    var body: some View {
        GeometryReader { geometry in
            // ... view code in here
        }
        .onAppear {
            var rows = Array(repeating: GridItem(.flexible()), count: currentGrid.rowTotal)
        }
    }
```

This creates the view and, before showing it, the grid is set to its proper value.

3. The message *'ScenarioView' initializer is inaccessible due to "private" protection level* seems clear: you must provide a value to to the variable `scenarios` (it doesn't have a default value) but it's marked as `private`. Remove `private`.

```
@ObservedObject var scenarios: OutputOverview
```

Then, remember to pass a value of type `OutputOverview` for the variable when you call the view:

```
ScenarioView(scenarios: aVariableOfTypeOutputOverview)
```

4. The type mismatch error you get inside the `@main` code is also clear - you have defined a variable of type `Scenario`:

```
@State var scenarios = Scenario(scenarioNumber: 1, date: Date.now)
```

but `ScenarioView` requires another type:

```
@ObservedObject private var scenarios: OutputOverview
```

One of them needs change for your code to work.

Comment: Many thanks for your comments, much appreciated. Just to reply: your solution for point 2 does not seem to work in this code. When I include `.onAppear { var rows = Array(repeating: GridItem(.flexible()), count: currentGrid.rowTotal) }` and grey out the original var definition, Xcode mentions that it cannot find 'rows' in scope. But your other comments worked, so many thanks again.
    }